# php prime number using regex

Tags: php

kindly see below code. I used this to find prime number but the other tutorial said using this sequence **'/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/'** is there any different on the result? I already try but so far its the same result I'm just confuse that I might see the difference in the future..

```
 <?php

   function is_prime( $number )
    {
        $str = str_repeat("1", $number);

        if( preg_match( '/^1?$|^(111?)\1+$/', $str ) == 0 )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: its the same 11+ is 11 and one or more 1; 111 is already 1 more

Comment: @Espongha, are you interested only in regular expression or alternate solution work for your ?